# d.attributes[c] is undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to call another component in parent component.

```
<c:Paginator page="{!v.page}" pages="{!v.pages}" total="{!v.total}"/>
```

This is how I am calling component.This was working fine in winter 16 release but throwing error in summer 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and the issue got resolved after including a latest version of Jquery library(earlier I was using v1.11.3 now changed it to  v2.1.3). Anyhow this error was Mozilla browser specific, in Chrome the error message was different and more clear.

Comment: The different error messages in different browsers caused a lot of confusion here.

Comment: Thanks @Gopal I included latest version of jquery as 2.1.4 and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of events to communicate between components.
If parent to child, then `aura:method` is a simpler way

[Refer the Lightning developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods.htm)